# Jump to variable definition in elisp -emacs buffer

Tags: elisp, emacs24

In emacs, how to jump to the variable definition when the cursor is sitting on the variable itself.
like,

```
((let x 1)
 (message x))
```

The cursor is in second line on the variable, x. When the shortcut key is pressed, the emacs point must be moved to the first line middle.

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in function for that. In the general case, the symbol name could be generated dynamically, like with `gensym`. What have you tried so far? How did it fail?

Comment: i am not looking for runtime definition check, which gensym does. I mean to check variable definition during coding. I did try elisp-slime-nav but for some reasons, it doesn't work on even simplest lookups. It gives the error 'elisp-slime-nav-find-elisp-thing-at-point: Don't know how to find 'found-body''. More info on elisp-slime-nav @ http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/06/18/quickly-find-emacs-lisp-sources/

Comment: I guess elisp-slime-nav-find-elisp-thing-at-point can only find functions and variables that are defined with defvar?